# Как справиться с ошибкой [pool www] seems busy?

Tags: php, linux, nginx, php-fpm

Помогите настроить PHP-FPM.

My config / Конфигурация сервера:

```
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2697 v2 @ 2.70GHz
Core: 9
Ram: 10GB
Swap: 2GB
```

When reaching 200 online on a laravel project, PHP-FPM throws a 502 error. Here's what PHP-FPM writes in logs.
/ При достижении 200 онлайна на проекте, PHP-fpm отрубает.(примерно 10-15 секунд)

```
WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 32 children, there are 16 idle, and 186 total children
```

My last config pool.d / Последний конфиг

```
pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 400
pm.process_idle_timeout = 5s;
pm.max_requests = 0
```

1 PHP-fpm process takes 50mb on average.
In the old PHP-fpm config was such an error.

```
WARNING: [pool www] server reached max_children setting (100), consider raising it
```

Comment: Какая версия `php-fpm`? Какая ось? Опишите процесс установки.

Comment: nginx, php-fpm 7.2 , ubuntu 18.04

Comment: https://itdeer.ru/php7-2-na-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: совсем не то что нужно

Comment: Вы переустановите пыху